# What to use to click on flash elements on a page for automation?

Tags: automation

For html sites I would use selenium with python which doesn't work with flash. Wondering what tools people use to click flash elements like clicking buttons on a online flash game. I don't really like sikuli because it use's your mouse. I prefer headless and running multiple instances.